# Where should i do the django validations for objects and fields?

Tags: python, django, validation, django-rest-framework

I'm creating a django application which uses both the Django Rest Framework and the plain django-views as entrypoint for users.

I want to do validation both independant fields of my models, and on objects on a whole. For example:

- Field: is the entered licence-plate a correct one based on a regex function. No relation to other fields.
- Object: Is the entered zipcode valid for the given country. Relates to zipcode and country in the model.

For the DRF-API i use ModelSerializers which automatically call all the validators i have placed in my Model, for example:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    licence_plate = CharField(max_length=20, validators=[LicencePlateValidator])
```

Since the validator is given in the model, the API POSTS (because i use a ModelSerializer), as well as the objects created in the django admin backend are validated.

But when i want to introduce object level validation i need to do that in the serializer's **validate()**-method, which means objects are only validated in the API.

I'll have to override the model's save method too, to validate the objects created in the Django admin page.

**Question:** This seems a bit messy to me, is there a single point where i can put the object-level validators so that they are run at the API and in the admin-page, like i did with the field-level validation (I only have to put *them* in my model-declaration and everything is handled)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For model-level validation, there is the `Model.clean` method.

It is called if you are using `ModelForm` (which is used by default in `admin`), so this solves django views and admin parts.

On the other hand, DRF does not call models' `clean` automatically, so you will have to do it yourself in `Serializer.validate` (as the [doc](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/topics/3.0-announcement/#serializers) suggests). You can do it via a serializer mixin:

```
class ValidateModelMixin(object)
    def validate(self, attrs):
        attrs = super().validate(attrs)
        obj = self.Meta.model(**attrs)
        obj.clean()
        return attrs

class SomeModelSerializer(ValidateModelMixin, serializers.ModelSerializer):
    #...
    class Meta:
        model = SomeModel
```

or write a validator:

```
class DelegateToModelValidator(object):

    def set_context(self, serializer):
        self.model = serializer.Meta.model

    def __call__(self, attrs):
        obj = self.model(**attrs)
        obj.clean()

class SomeModelSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    #...
    class Meta:
        model = SomeModel
        validators = (
            DelegateToModelValidator(),
        )
```

Caveats:

- an extra instantiation of your models just to call `clean`
- you will still have to add the mixin/validator to your serializers

Comment: Ah tnx, this answer as well as Rahul's make it more clear to me that calling a model-validator in two places (once in the serializer , and once in the model)  *is* indeed the only way to validate through forms *and* the API. It gave me some ideas how to write some code in a more clean-way. I think i'll go the MixIn route... Seems cleaner to me.

Comment: This results in a

`TypeError: Direct assignment to the forward side of a many-to-many set is prohibited. Use users.set() instead.`

when it is used with models that have relations. Is there any workaround for this?

Answer (score 3):

You can **create a separate function `validate_zipcode_with_country(zipcode, country)`** which will take 2 arguments `zipcode` and `country`.

Then, we will **call this method in the serializer's `validate()` and in our model's `clean()`**.

```
from django.core.exceptions import ValidationError

def validate_zipcode_with_country(zipcode, country):
    # check zipcode is valid for the given country 
    if not valid_zipcode:
        raise ValidationError("Zipcode is not valid for this country.")
```

Then in your `serializers.py`, you need to call this function in your `validate()` function.

```
class MySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):   

    def validate(self, attrs):
        zipcode = attrs.get('zipcode')
        country = attrs.get('country')
        validate_zipcode_with_country(zipcode, country) # call the function
        ...
```

Similarly, you need to override the model's `clean()` and call this function.

```
class MyModel(models.Model):

    def clean(self):        
        validate_zipcode_with_country(self.zipcode, self.country) # call this function
        ...
```