# Common custom validation for DRF and Django admin

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have user table in which have to put unique email constrain on staff users and unique phone constrain on non staff user. Now I want to maintain this constrain in DRF API and in Django admin, how to achieve this without code duplication.

As I see from DRF 3.0 onwards, all validations are performed explicitly for serializer (If I have overwritten unique_validation or clean method to perform conditional validation, I have to write this custom validation separately for serializer as well) so how to write a custom validation that works both for DRF API and Django admin without code duplication ?

Comment: Add validators at the model level

Comment: @utkbansal but then as per DRF documentation model level validation will not apply on DRF serializer  http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/validators/ "With REST framework the validation is performed entirely on the serializer class."

Comment: @r.bhardwaj you should add constraints to model level. Then try/catch exceptions in serializer and in admin form or admin class itself. There is no way to create common validation for admin and APIView

Comment: @IvanSemochkin Understood. But here is a better solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32921956/where-should-i-do-the-django-validations-for-objects-and-fields#answer-32923868 what do you think of that ?

Answer (score 3):

If your model doesn't have nested relationships, this should work.

```
class ValidateModelMixin(object)
    def validate(self, attrs):
        attrs = super().validate(attrs)
        obj = self.Meta.model(**attrs)
        obj.clean()
        return attrs

class SomeModelSerializer(ValidateModelMixin, serializers.ModelSerializer):
    #...
    class Meta:
        model = SomeModel
```

But in my case, I have nested models and I need to override create() and update() methods in serializer. My solution to keep validations in only one place:

```
def create(self, validated_data):
        # Remove nested and M2m relationships from validated_data
        firstmodel_set = validated_data.pop('firstmodel_set') if 'firstmodel_set' in validated_data else []
        .....
        # Get instance of project
        instance = Project(**validated_data)
        instance.clean()

        # If clean method doesn't raise any exception, create.
        project = instance.save()
        ......
```

If you want serialize validations messages .. maybe something like that will help you ...

```
def validate_instance(instance):
    try:
        # Call model validation
        instance.clean()
    except ValidationError as e:
        raise serializers.ValidationError(e)
```

Or you can use **Signals** and make validations on pre_save().
Take a look in https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/signals/

Comment: I see in `validate_instance` that you catch `ValidationError`, then raise it as `serializers.ValidationError`. Are these two exceptions really so different that you need the try/except block? If not, having `instance.clean()` as the entire body of the function is sufficient.

Comment: @MattMcCarthy Unfortunately they are different enough for your frontend to notice. Currently I like this approach: https://github.com/HackSoftware/Django-Styleguide#handle-exceptions-in-apis, contained and explicit. Or you could do the same in drf exception handler.

Answer (score 0):

**FOR API:**
Create a serializer for UserRegistration and implement validate method with two condition one for unique email and another for phone number.
something like as :

```
class UserCreateSerializer(ModelSerializer):
   class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ['email','phone','...']
   def validate(self, data):
        """user email phone validator """

        user_qs = User.objects.filter(email=data['email'], is_staff=True)
        if user_qs.exists():
            raise ValidationError({"email":"This user has already registered."})
        user_phone = User.objects.filter(phone=data['phone'], is_active=True, is_staff=False)
        if user_phone.exists():
            raise ValidationError({"phone":"Phone number already exists."})
        return data
```

**FOR WEB:** 
If you have created form for registration then in your form implement clean method as validate in serializer, above.

```
class UserCreateForm(ModelForm):

    class Meta:
            model = User
            fields = ['email','phone','...']
    def clean(self):
            """user email phone validator """

            user_qs = User.objects.filter(email=self.cleaned_data['email'], is_staff=True)
            if user_qs.exists():
                raise ValidationError({"email":"This user has already registered."})
            user_phone = User.objects.filter(phone=self.cleaned_data['phone'], is_active=True, is_staff=False)
            if user_phone.exists():
                raise ValidationError({"phone":"Phone number already exists."})
            return data
```

Comment: Okay, that means we have to define the validation for DRF Serializer and Django Admin form separately, there is no common way, right ?

Comment: If I need to validate two fields at the same time like: match name with id togather, what i need to do?

Comment: I got my solution